# Windows 7 recongizes lan cable, but there is not network or internet connection

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, lan

It's a while that I'm facing with this problem.
I connect the lan cable to my PC, but there is no network connections or any internet connection, but the computer recognizes the lan cable (because in "network adapters" section, the red cross goes away).

I changed my lan card and tried again, but the problem persists, I also tried it inside "safe mode with networking" and it had no changes.

Do you have any ideas what should I do next?
guys please don't suggest me to change my operation system.

Comment: out of curiosity what exactly is on the other end of the cable?

Comment: inside curiosity, there is a router :D, but i did check it with other lan ports on the same router and with another laptop but it didn't work too/

Comment: So, 2 different computers connected to different ports on the router, and none have an internet connection? This suggests your router is at fault. Have you a different one you can test?

Comment: nope, other devices which connect to the same router work fine, but this PC doesn't, there is the point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All was the "Hotspot Shield"!

I went under network and sharing center, change adapter settings and in the properties of Local Area Network, just unchecked unusual ticks. so it's ok now and working fine :D

Answer (score 0):

Try a different cable if you haven't already.  Just because a physical connection is established doesn't mean that all wires are working properly in the cable.  Next, open a command prompt and see if you can ping 127.0.0.1.  This will ensure that your TCP/IP stack is functioning.  Next, ping the gateway (address of your router).  If you all of these are successful then the problem is in your router somewhere.  If you can't ping the router, but the stack is working, its possible that your computer is set up with a static IP address and needs to switched to DHCP.  It could also have the wrong default gateway assigned.  Ensure your default gateway is correct.  Lastly, try disabling IPv6 under advanced features > properties of your network connection and ensure that IPv4 is enabled.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I checked the cable and it works fine on my laptop, but not on the pc.
about the instructions, I just can ping 127.0.0.1, and it doesn't recognize the network so that we could say it's dhcp problem

Comment: Are you getting an IP address?  What is your default gateway address and what is the address of the interface on the router?  Is your router handing out DHCP addresses?  It's possible that DHCP has run out of addresses on your router.  Just brainstorming here.

Comment: Nope! My PC doesn't get any ip address, and about running out of addresses, it's funny :D

Comment: You could try turning off DHCP on your machine and assigning it a static IP within the same subnet of your router.  I.E.  If your other machines are getting IP's like 192.168.1.2 and .3, 4, 5, etc, then the subnet you are on is 192.168.1.0.  You will most likely be able to give your machine anything from 3 - 254.  Make sure default gateway is set correctly.  It's the address of your router.  Usually  .1 or .2.

Comment: Alternatively, you may need to reset the TCP/IP stack.  netsh int ip reset C:\netsh.log.txt
netsh winsock reset